# Does Kakashi's Sharingan use more chakra than the Uchiha clan members?

Tags: naruto

As in *Naruto*, Kakashi used his Sharingan only during a combat.

Where as the Uchiha clan members (mainly Itachi and Madara), used their Sharingan almost all the time.

So, does the Sharingan consume more chakra in the case of Kakashi as compared to an Uchiha?

Comment: I have edited your post , if it change the content you can roll back

Comment: The main reason is, Kakashi is not an Uchiha

Comment: @mirroroftruth That's what I want to know. In his case does it consumes more chakra?

Comment: yes it does consume , and he is not uchiha so he can't deactivate it so he cover it when not needed

Comment: Alright, could you pls add some more detail and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To directly answer the question, **NO**, it doesn't.

Theoretically, I think the consumption/amount of chakra using Sharingan comparing to other *Uchihas* is the *same*. They only differ on *how they use them with their bodies*. We all know that Uchihas (mainly Itachi and Madara) has bodies mainly adapted to use Sharingan thus making them **efficiently** use it in battles. On the other hand, Kakashi retains his body (which is not Uchiha's) causing him to use Sharingan inefficiently which in return produces waste chakra during its usage.

Sharingans are like weapons - same weapon requires equal strength in order to use them. But no different body can use the same weapon.

---

Don't get me wrong, the other answer is still correct. But does not necessarily answers the question.

**Update**

In addition, as per @mirroroftruth, Kakashi can't deactivate his Sharingan. Active Sharingan constantly use chakra.

Comment: your answer is also right ,for one reason you should still say that Kakashi use more chakra than Uchiha because he can't deactivate sharingan, active sharingan definitely use chakra,

Answer (score 4):

The answer comes right from the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake#Sharingan) as @mirroroftruth said:

> When he first recieved it, Kakashi's Sharingan only two tomoe. Later,
>   the traumatic loss of his dear friend Rin Nohara at his own hand
>   caused Kakashi's Sharingan to fully mature. Because he is not of
>   direct Uchiha heritage, Kakashi was unable to deactivate this dōjutsu.
>   This forced him keep it covered when not needed as it also consumed
>   much greater chakra reserves than an Uchiha, leaving him bedridden if
>   overused. Because of this, Kakashi only relied on it when absolute
>   necessary. In Part I, he could only handle using it for a short while
>   in battle before suffering somewhat crippling effects and severe
>   fatigue. In Part II, his efficiency with maintaining it greatly
>   increased, able to use it for seemingly an entire day without any
>   adverse effects.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as explained by the Second Hokage : 
Strong feelings in the Uchiha clan folks had the potential to release a certain type of chakra in their brains. This was visible in their eyes as a red color, which is the Sharingan. The stronger their emotions, the stronger their Sharingan powers grew. They were able to awaken Mangekyo in cases of extreme mental trauma [either self-inflicted / suffered]. Very few have actually done it in the series.

Having said that, Kakashi did not awaken a Sharingan, it is Uchiha Obito's eye.
He was able to use it by means of his own chakra, but since that did not originate in him, the amount of chakra consumed was higher. Similar to using a scroll for a Suiton [Water] style jutsu, without having an affinity for that type.

Since, he could not control the sharingan to the level of actually using whenever required, he covered it with his headband. This doesnot mean he was using the sharingan always, he had to lift up his headband to use it [during combat / when required]

He does have vast reserves of chakra as displayed by his use of copied techniques, body activation and his own elemental manipulation, which are not easy without that. But Sharingan is something external to him, and he needs to focus more chakra to it.

Wanted to add upon the wiki reference with some additional info.
HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as though Kakashi is not an Uchiha by blood, his body does not have the required physical strength to use the blood trait of the Sharingan therefore it requires a lot more  of his chakra to use in comparison to an Uchiha's usage of the Sharingan.

This works for any and all Dojutsu, if you are not the original wielder and don't have the genetics for it, it will be extremely difficult for you to wield.

While Obito did in fact have the spiritual energy to use the Rinnegan, he didn't have any bloodline relations to the Senju or Uzumaki and couldn't use the Rinnegan at all.